# create a coinhive fork

Tags: mining, miners, coin-hive

I want to create my own coinhive clone. What do I need to start my own service like coinhive?
I know that I need the following:
-blockchain (serverside)
-javascript miner (clientside)
-pool

what else do I need for my coinhive fork and does anyone know a tutorial that explains how to program a miner?

thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

I did exactly this recently. Take a look at:

https://github.com/jtgrassie/xmr-wasm